# Opposite of Java .equals() method?

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write a little block of code in Java with a do-while loop that asks the user's name. If it isn't the name the code is looking for, then it just repeats itself. For example,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner();
do { 
   System.out.println("whats your name?"); 
   String name = scan.nextLine(); 
} while ("jack".equals(name));  ////// <<<<
```

It's where I marked with `<<<<` that I don't know what to do. I need something like `!=`, but that does not work with strings.

So what can I put here?

Comment: You can use the negative boolean operator: `while (!jack.equals(name))`.

Comment: `!my_string.equals(other_string)`

Comment: @Vulcan: that's an answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels StackOverflow might've considered it a "trival answer" and auto-converted it to a comment.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I don't believe that simple answers like that deserve rep, and I've got a (bad?) habit of posting in a comment rather than a community wiki answer.

Comment: I guess you're right. I always suspect that questions that get 4 answers in 5 minutes only mean that the original poster hasn't read the tutorials.

Answer (score 12):

The exclamation point `!` represents negation or compliment. `while(!"jack".equals(name)){ }`

Comment: My mistake. Edited for accuracy.

Comment: @acdcjunior `jack` appeared to be a variable in the original, poor formatting of the question.

Comment: @Vulcan I was talking about the original one, actually. It was `"jack` then (thus the *seems*). Right now it clearly is a `String`.

Answer (score 5):

The boolean not ! operator is the cleanest way. Of course you could also say

```
if ("jack".equals(name) == false) { ... }
```

or you could say

```
if ("jack".equals(name) != true) { ... }
```

Beware if calling `.equals()` on an object that could be `null` or you'll get a `NullPointerException`. In that case, something like...

```
if !((myVar == yourVar) || ((yourVar != null) && yourVar.equals(myVar))) { ... }
```

... would guard against an `NullPointerException` and be true if they're no equal, including them both not being `null`. Quite a brain-twister huh? I think that logic is sound, if ugly. That's why I write a `StringUtil` class containing this logic in many projects!

That's why it's a better convention to invoke the `.equals()` method on the string literal rather than the String you're testing.

Comment: +1 almost too many info, but correct! Tip: format you code using CTRL+K, makes it much easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

Put the "!" in from of jack. That will solve if I understand the question correctly.